# Recursive scan of folder tree C

Tags: c

I need to create a C program running on linux, that recursively scans folders searching files. Is this possible? I am a beginner in C and so far I could not find anything. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I don't believe, that you found nothing

Comment: What OS? Have you tried anything yet, or at least what are the results of your searches? How about `find . -name "filename"`  ;)

Comment: In linux. Need to create a script that has the same function as the find command

Comment: A bash script or C code, as you tagged the question?

Comment: It's "source code", not "script." C isn't a scripted language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at Glib, there are some [file utilities](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html) that can be helpful here.

More specifically, you can use [g_dir_open](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-dir-open) function on every file in a directory. If this function sets the `GError**error` pointer non-null, then you have tried to open a file, otherwise you've just parsed into a subdir...

Your code should look like this:

```
void parse(const gchar *path)
{
  GError *error;
  GDir *dir = g_dir_open(path, 0, error);
  if(error) 
  {
    // this is a file, not a dir, or a dir which could not be opened...
    // you can put all the processing for your file here.
  }
  else
  {
    gchar *elem;
    while(( elem=g_dir_read_name(dir) ))
    {
      parse(elem);
      free(elem);
    }
    g_dir_close(dir);
  }
}
```

Say that you have a folder of 10 files, then the parse function will call itself 10 times, once for each file. (Just try it in a debugger!)
**0th parse call:** opens the directory, then reaches the while loop and calls parse the 1st time for the first file
**1st parse call:** cannot open the file as directory, so the function ends in the first part of the if block.
**back to the 0th parse call:** iterates the while loop, calls parse the 2nd time for the next file
**2nd parse call:** cannot open the file as directory, so the function ends in the first part of the if block.
**back to the 0th parse call:** iterates the while loop, calls parse the 3rd time for the next file
...
**back to the 0th parse call:** no more files in the dir, the loop ends.

This is called recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I looked at a library here. It is very useful! But, after studying the code that you posted here, I'm not sure if this is what I want because if I understand this code well, so you opens the specified folder that searches, and if therein only files  then  method end. I need to extract the names of all the files and folders contained in the specified folder tree.

Comment: Or, if I have a folder that contains 10 files, for example, this code would open the folder and finished by the first of the files because it's not a folder

Comment: Yes, now I understand. It's really very nice script! Useful! Thank you! I edited it, to search for file and folder names, the input parameter "name the file being searched". But would need to add one more input parameter, the number of threads that will be done in parallel browsing. Is it possible for recursive browsing?

For example: I have a folder in there for another 3 folders and a few files. The script would start to create a thread that will search through the first folder, and when I find another folder, create a new thread that will search through the second folder .... and so on.

Comment: well, you can do that but it will be actually slower than the single-threaded version (it is very expensive to create threads). I would not dynamically open threads but create a pipeline that is a handful of threads and I would assign parsing calls as tasks to them. (there are again libraries which can manage this sort of stuff...[try intel cilk](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-cilk-plus))