# Vala List Folder & Subfolder content

Tags: vala

I use this code, to list my folder content as a TreeView.

```
    try {
        string directory = "/home/malte/.password-store/";
        Dir dir = Dir.open (directory, 0);
        string? name = null;

        while ((name = dir.read_name ()) != null) {
            string path = Path.build_filename (directory, name);

            if (FileUtils.test (path, FileTest.IS_REGULAR)) {
                list_store.append (out iter);
                list_store.set (iter, 0, name);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileError err) {
        stderr.printf (err.message);
    }
```

This really works perfectly. But I want to list my subfolder contents, too. And in the subfolders are folders too. Can somebody give me a hint how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just make the file listing a function that calls itself recursively.

[Here is an example in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878834/recursive-scan-of-folder-tree-c#13881838)

Pseudocode:

```
void list_files_recursive (string dir, List<string> filenames) {
   foreach (filename in dir) {
     if (file_is_dir(filename)) {
       list_files_recursive (filename, filenames);
     } else {
       filenames.add (filename);
     }
   }
}
```

As for how to add them to a tree store instead of a list store that is a different question, but I'm sure there are examples somewhere for Vala and tree stores.